# Postman dont sent req.body if use from-data for input data

Tags: javascript, express, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

[this code midleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCI8u.png) this code

where I input using the body/raw request it is successful but when I input data using from-data it always fails

how to solve this problem

[iam Use From-data login fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57vp9.png),`this code`
[if iam use www-from login succes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELrml.png),
[this code header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/193li.png) if i use raw login `your text`

when I did console.log to see the req that was done it was empty { }

I need from-data to upload files

when I did console.log to see the req that was done it was empty { }

I need succes login use from-data?

Comment: You need to share the `UserRoute.js` code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.